# pandas dataframe select row by full multiindex entry and some column entry

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi indexed `DataFrame` in `pandas` and i would like to select a row by the following condition:

Let's say we have columns `'a','b','c'` and indicies `'i1','i2'`

```
print(df)

           a   b   c
i1  i2  
10 2.0    10  34   ..
   2.0    11  45   ..
   2.0    12  36   ..
20 2.0    10  15   ..
   2.0    18  34   ..
   2.0    16  46   ..
```

Now I would like to select for each unique muliindex entry the row where column `'a'` becomes maximal. So I wrote

```
for entry in df.index.unique():
    max_a = df.loc[entry,'a'].max()
```

and now I would like to select that row and append it to another dataframe, let's say `dfout`

```
dfout=dfout.append(df[(df.index.values == entry) & (df['fi'] == max_a)])
```

This raises `invalid type comparison`, probably because I try to compare tuples, not sure...
Can anyone explain to me, how I would be able to select exactly that row the correct way? Maybe there is even a much nicer way to select all these `max('a')` rows for all unique entries of `df.index`.

edit:

`df.index.values` is of type `numpy.ndarray`

`entry` is of type `tuple`

Maybe this helps for answering my question.

Comment: is that your entire `df`? It looks like you have more values on the columns than you do index entries. Could you post a bit of code that constructs exactly the kind of `df` your using

Comment: You are exactly right. I do have one and the same index entry for several rows. In principle I can change that by changing the index columns I read with `pd.read_csv` such that I have unique indicies, but how I do it right now is acutally what I want. For a given set of index values I have several rows and I want to get only the row where the value in column `'a'` becomes maximal.

Comment: Ah, maybe you are right, I did not format the output properly. Now the second index entry is repeated in each row. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with your data in that you want to identify rows with the maximum `a` per unique index item but your index isn't unique.

I would typically go about it like this

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['i1', 'i2']).a.idxmax()]
```

But look at the `idxmax` results

```
df.groupby(level=['i1', 'i2']).a.idxmax()

i1  i2 
10  2.0    (10, 2.0)
20  2.0    (20, 2.0)
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Since the index isn't unique, the `loc` call will just return all of them again.

```
df.loc[df.groupby(level=['i1', 'i2']).a.idxmax()]

         a   b   c
i1 i2             
10 2.0  10  34  ..
   2.0  11  45  ..
   2.0  12  36  ..
20 2.0  10  15  ..
   2.0  18  34  ..
   2.0  16  46  ..
```

---

So... we need to make a unique index so this technique will work

**Option 1**
*`reset_index`*
I could have assigned the dataframe with the reset index to a new variable and used `loc` but I know that my new index will be the same as positions so I went ahead and used `iloc`

```
df.iloc[df.reset_index().groupby(['i1', 'i2']).a.idxmax()]

         a   b   c
i1 i2             
10 2.0  12  36  ..
20 2.0  18  34  ..
```

**Option 2**
*`cumcount`*
Add another level to the existing index to make it unique.

```
d1 = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=['i1', 'i2']).cumcount(), append=True)
d1.loc[d1.groupby(level=['i1', 'i2']).a.idxmax()].reset_index(-1, drop=True)

         a   b   c
i1 i2             
10 2.0  12  36  ..
20 2.0  18  34  ..
```

---

In my opinion, option 1 is prettier.

Answer (score 0):

I took the example dataframe from the pandas MultiIndex documentation page and did the following

```
def mklbl(prefix,n):
        return ["%s%s" % (prefix,i)  for i in range(n)]


miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([mklbl('A',4),
                                       mklbl('B',2),
                                       mklbl('C',4),
                                       mklbl('D',2)])


micolumns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a','foo'),('a','bar'),
                                        ('b','foo'),('b','bah')],
                                       names=['lvl0', 'lvl1'])


dfmi = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(len(miindex)*len(micolumns)).reshape((len(miindex),len(micolumns))),
                     index=miindex,
                     columns=micolumns).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)

dfmi.index = dfmi.index.droplevel(3)
dfmi_ = dfmi.reset_index()
dfmi_.columns = dfmi_.columns.droplevel(1)
```

the dataframe should now look roughly the same as your example

```
>> dfmi_.head()
lvl0 level_0 level_1 level_2   a   a   b   b
0         A0      B0      C0   1   0   3   2
1         A0      B0      C0   5   4   7   6
2         A0      B0      C1   9   8  11  10
3         A0      B0      C1  13  12  15  14
4         A0      B0      C2  17  16  19  18
```

now you can just do a `groupby` and `idxmax` to get the max index per group

```
>> idxmax = dfmi_.groupby('level_0')['a'].idxmax()
>> dfmi_.loc[idxmax]
lvl0 level_0 level_1 level_2    a    a    b    b
15        A0      B1      C3   61   60   63   62
15        A0      B1      C3   61   60   63   62
31        A1      B1      C3  125  124  127  126
31        A1      B1      C3  125  124  127  126
47        A2      B1      C3  189  188  191  190
47        A2      B1      C3  189  188  191  190
63        A3      B1      C3  253  252  255  254
63        A3      B1      C3  253  252  255  254
```

Comment: In the last `DataFrame` there should be a row with index `A0      B0      C0`. More specifically exactly the row where column `'a'` takes `5` as a value (as that is the highest value for the all rows with index `A0      B0      C0` for `dfmi_`). (I am not sure why you have 2 columns with the same keyword `'a'`. That is kind of confusing in this context and makes it a bit more complicated)

Comment: look at the actual `df` the highest value is not `5`, the first print out is showing just the `.head`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
import pandas as pd

dfout = pd.DataFrame()

for entry in df.index.unique():
    max_a = df.loc[entry,'a'].max()
    dftemp = df.loc[entry,:].copy() # not sure if the copy is necessary
    dftemp = dftemp[dftemp['a'] == max_a]
    dfout = dfout.append(dftemp)
```

But this really feels more like a work around than a solution how to select a row with a

```
# pseudo code:
multiindex entry == (1,2,...,n)
```

and a

```
# pseudo code:
column 'keyword' entry == max_a
```